# Scrapy doesn't download files, but data is clean/complete and there are no errors

Tags: python, download, scrapy

I run this and I get all the data cleanly from the `yield article` when I run it in the command line, but I don't actually download the files in the second function, `download`.  The `files` field in the csv is empty and the files aren't showing up in the local_folder directory.  I don't get any error messages, which is making it hard to troubleshoot. Can someone please point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

thespider.py

```py
import re
import scrapy
import unidecode
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from dhqscraper.items import FileDownloader

class DhqSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dhq'
    allowed_domains = ['digitalhumanities.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/index.html']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'index.html')), 
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'vol'), callback='parse_article'),        
        )

    def parse_article(self, response):
        article = { 
            'title' : response.css('h1.articleTitle').xpath('normalize-space(text())').get(default='').strip(),
            'author' : response.css('div.author a').xpath('normalize-space(text())').getall(),
            'year' : unidecode.unidecode(response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[0].get()),
            'volume' : unidecode.unidecode(response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[1].get()),
            'xmllink' : response.urljoin(response.xpath('(//div[@class="toolbar"]/a[contains(@href, ".xml")]/@href)[1]').get()),
        }
        article ['author'] = [unidecode.unidecode(i) for i in article['author']] 
        yield article
        
        def download(self, response):
            file_url = article['xmllink']
            item = FileDownloader()
            item['file_urls'] = [file_url]
            yield item
```

items.py

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class FileDownloader(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field
```

settings.py

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
FILES_STORE = 'local_folder'
```

Comment: you say that you are get the data cleanly , Where you get this data ?

Comment: From the ```yield article``` online 28.  Using command line ```scrapy crawl dhq```

I'm not getting the files from the ```yield item``` on line 34.

Comment: Try this command  `scrapy crawl dhq -t csv -o data.csv` and see if you get a filled csv file

Comment: No, I'm not getting anything from the second function.

```def download(self, response)......```

Comment: Why would you get anything from the download function?